# How can I fix [Ycm] Invalid ycm path in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Vs code whenever i open VS code application this message is pop up.

```
[Ycm] Invalid ycm path
```

What is the meaning of this message and how do i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi，I have fixed this note，but looks like ycm does not work.

--

I use [this link](https://gist.github.com/ChengLong/6208775) to fix.

My command have some differences.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git

cd YouCompleteMe

git submodule update --init --recursive

cd third_party

mkdir ycmd_build

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" . /Users/xx/software_cfg/ycm/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

Then copy 'ycm_core.cpython-310-darwin.so' to VS Code ycmd path.

[image]

--

After these setting，I found ycm still not work.

Just add one dir path in [Ycmd: Path], the note will disappear.